# How to test a function called within a thread in ruby using minitest?

Tags: ruby, minitest, webmock

The function fetch_details is called within the thread. It has a post request which raises the CustomError in case of failure. I need to test the 
CustomError without actually making the actual post request.

```
Thread.new {
      begin
        details = fetch_details(a, b)
        param1, param2 = parse_details(details, b)
        post_result("Success", url)
      rescue CustomError => e  
        post_result(e.message, url)
      end
    }
```

How do I stub the post request inside the fetch_details function to raise the Custom Error?

Comment: what is the purpose of this test?

Comment: The error message is displayed on a error logging page. I have defined custom error messages for different scenarios but without making actual calls how do I replicate them for tests?

Comment: Have a look at this article https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/mocking-in-ruby-with-minitest